# Can't create Java VM rjb ubuntu

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rjb

I am using rjb to connect java classes in my rails application...
But I am getting this error `can't create Java VM`
My ruby -v gave me

```
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

and java --version

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

I went through this post [Error “can't create Java VM” trying to use Ruby Java Bridge (RJB) gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818322/error-cant-create-java-vm-trying-to-use-ruby-java-bridge-rjb-gem) but the problem is I can not install 32 bit java as it is needed by some other application

Answer (score 1):

I would download the jdk from oracle (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), the version you need. Then for your application set JAVA_HOME to that install directory. You can have multiple different jvms installed on a system.